# After Publish MVC5 App other website not working

Tags: iis-7.5

i have publish MVC5 app is working fine , but after this deploy other website not working and i am getting mentioned below.

Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive
Line 81:

Comment: Is there any more information you could give. What is the other website?

Comment: thanks my friend , actually other website VS2008 , VS2010 Application